# Assigning void pointer to itself

Tags: c

Recently I've faced with a strange code snippet. It's a part of memory pool code written in C, which ( of course ) intensively uses address arithmetic.

Omitting redundant details, I added some comments instead of them:

```
void *head;
/* some memory allocation stuff, including assigning  allocated memory address to head */

/* allocating some memory pages */

/* OK, now allocation stuff is finished. head pointer still contains valid address */

head = *(void **)head;
```

What is `head = *(void **)head;`? We assign head to itself? Why? And for what? I understand this line as *"we are treating head as pointer to pointer to void, i.e. address of void pointer. Then we're dereferencing it, so next we'll get pointer to void. And next assigning this pointer to head ( head to itself ?? )"*.

Obviously, I'm wrong, because it's production code example that works successfully. But it doesn't make any sense for me. What the trick is it, guys?

P.S. Unfortunately, I can't paste full snippet due to NDA. But there is nothing special there anymore.

Comment: Pointing `head` to the first page probably. The leading `*` is very important.

Comment: Without knowing what `head` was initialized to do, it's impossible to say what the purpose of the new value is.

Comment: @MadPhysicist `head=malloc(...)`

Answer (score 2):

`head = *(void**)head;` assigns a pointer (`void*`) that `head` points to to `head` itself.

Comment: But head points to `malloc` result ( `head = malloc(...)` ), i.e. to a `void*`, not `void**`

Comment: @Uroboros The fact that `head` points to a `malloc`ed memory isn't revelant. Some line prior to `head = *(void**)head;` probably writes some `void*` to the first `sizeof(void*)` bytes of that `malloc`ed memory chunk.

Comment: That's unbelievable, but a real fact. That's why I'm stuck :(

Comment: @Uroboros Why exactly is that unbelievable? It doesn't sound unusual to me at all.

Comment: There are no lines writing void pointer to the first sizeof(void*) bytes of memory chunk. This fact is unbelievable, I mean

Comment: @Uroboros It has to be there. Maybe some structure is written into that memory chunk, and a first member of said structure is a pointer?

Answer (score 0):

if `head` points to a linked list structure and the first element of the linked list is the pointer to the next element, your construct is equivalent to

```
head = head->next;
```

when the structures aren't opaque.